# Ubuntu 19.04: Packages held back / E: Unable to locate package libsmnp30

Tags: package-management, wine

So, during the update process some of the files are greyed out and can't be checked: the Wine update and some app regarding the temperature (I'm sorry, can't remember right now). I'm trying to install new Wine with the terminal, but it's "held back".

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libsnmp30 lm-sensors winehq-staging
```

However when I go:

```
sudo apt-get install libsmnp30 lm-sensors winehq-staging
```

The terminal replies:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsmnp30
```

What do I do? How do I install the greyed out updates?

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libsmnp30  shows there is no Ubuntu package for any supported release by that name.  It was not a Ubuntu repository package that is asking for it, so check with the source of the package wanting it (esp. wherever it came from) - though it could also be just a typo, eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libsnmp30&searchon=names shows package `libsnmp30` is available  (and I know what SNMP is unlike smnp where i have no clue)

Comment: 1. You have a typo - the package is named [`libsnmp30`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=libsnmp30). 2. Please add output of `apt-cache policy libsnmp30 lm-sensors winehq-staging`. I can install two packages on both 19.04 and 19.10.

Comment: 1) Thank you, you're right. There was a typo. Still:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsnmp30 : Depends: libsensors5 (>= 1:3.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
 lm-sensors : Depends: libsensors5 (>= 1:3.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 4.18~disco)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: The output of apt-cache policy libsnmp30 lm-sensors winehq-staging is:

libsnmp30:
  Installed: 5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.18.10.1
  Candidate: 5.7.3+dfsg-5ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
     5.7.3+dfsg-5ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 Packages
     5.7.3+dfsg-5ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.18.10.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: lm-sensors:
  Installed: 1:3.4.0-4
  Candidate: 1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:3.5.0-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 1:3.4.0-4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: winehq-staging:
  Installed: 4.12.1~disco
  Candidate: 4.18~disco
  Version table:
     4.18~disco 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
     4.17~disco 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
     4.16~disco 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
     4.15~disco 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages

Comment: 4.14~disco 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
     4.13~disco 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
 *** 4.12.1~disco 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: 4.12~disco 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
     4.11~disco 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
     4.10~disco 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
     4.9~disco 500

Comment: 500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
     4.8~disco 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages
     4.7~disco 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu disco/main amd64 Packages

Comment: I've written down the missed packages as they appear in the Software Updater:

1. WINE is not an emulator - runs MS Windows programs
2. Utilities to read temperature/voltage/fan sensors

Comment: Anyone? Any ideas?